# How to do a recursive call with a stack function in MASM assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

I am working on a program to calculate the first seven values of a Fibonacci number sequence. I was given some C to base it off, yet I am not sure what I have is doing everything quite right. This is only the second time I have done a program in MASM with a stack and I'm not sure on what I did was correct.
This is what I was given in C:

```c
//Fibonacci Series using Recursion
#include<stdio.h>
int fib(int n)
{
   if (n <= 1)
      return n;
   return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
 
int main ()
{
  int n = 9;
  int result = fib(n);
  return 0;
}
```

And this is what I have in MASM. Do I have a proper stack call?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword
.data
nValue DWORD 9
val DWORD 0
.code
fib PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 12
    mov EAX, [EBP+12]
    mov [EBP-8], ECX

    cmp ECX, 1 ;compare if greater than 1
    JG L1 
    L1: mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
    JG L2
        L2: sub ecx, 1
        sub ecx, 2
        mov val, ecx
        push val
        call fib
     
fib ENDP

main PROC
    mov ecx, nValue
    push nValue
    call fib
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: You're missing `ret` statements from both the end of `fib` and `main`, and your epilog in `fib` is misplaced.

Comment: Also, neither `JG L1; L1:` nor `JG L2; L2:` do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is many errors and misunderstunding

- val variable is useless
- your working with input parameter and local variable is wrong. Better way is let assembler do his work. You can define input parameters and local variables like this. All prolog and epilog code is inserted by assembler in right manner. Please check final code by any debugger.

```
    fib PROC param1:DWORD
    local localVar:DWORD

    mov EAX, param1
    mov localVar, EAX
    ....
    ret
    fib ENDP
```

- at end of main missing also ExitProcess call.
- recursive calculation of fibonaci numbers is also wrong.
- others errors - missing ret, and wrong condition jumps was already mentioned.